# At the risk of sounding dumb: I want to make an HTML audio player that uses <canvas> for interaction. Thoughts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Basically I am attempting to make an HTML5 audio player but want to do the majority of the controls with canvas. Why? I want to try something new while learning something new. I have gotten everything working so far - that is, a seekable timeline, play/pause buttons, etc. - by essentially using mouse coordinates to decide what the user is clicking on.

Im mainly curious what the more experienced web developers out there think of this. Is it dumb? Is there an issue you think I may not foresee?

I'll post some code if anyone is really interested, but I havent had any issues so far so I dont really need and troubleshooting.

Thanks!

Comment: Haha I like this question: Nothing's wrong, and it's working great - but I'm scared!

Comment: Well its like a screwdriver - you can go and make an ugly one that will work the same as the one you bought for $1. But if you buy one you will never experience the joy of month of melting iron and hammering your tool so it can be usable... and pretty as much as possible. So basically if you want to get how events/canvas/JS work, opt for melting/hammering. And if you want to get the job done and go on with your life, opt for a proven solution. :)

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some of your code! I've been working on a small html 5 tile based game and I struggled a bit with how to do 'event' handling, so I'm curious how you did it. This is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/6bS6r/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a learning experience?  Great!  You've clearly figured out how `<canvas>` works, how to manipulate objects on-screen, and how to make those objects interactive.

In a production app?  Not a chance.  What immediately comes to mind:

- It's not accessible.  `<button>` has a semantic meaning that a screen reader can take advantage of.  A canvas means nothing; in your example, a blind user has no idea there even are play/pause buttons, much less how to activate them.
- You're reinventing the wheel for no real gain.  Let the browser handle the details of whether an object was clicked.  Have you accounted for zoom?  Keyboard interaction?
- You lose out on a [wide array](http://jqueryui.com/) of pre-baked widgets.
- Your implementation is guaranteed to have a bug somewhere.  A `<button>` is guaranteed to be a  button.

Comment: Much appreciated. I hadn't thought about accessibility and I really appreciate you bringing it up - it's something I've worked hard to keep in mind during past projects. To be honest, this WAS intended to be used in a larger production, but I will surely go a different route. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with this idea, especially if you’re doing it to try something new. What I would add is that `<canvas>` is generally not that suitable for interactive widgets, although there are exceptions. I suspect you will find that in the end you’re better off using HTML/CSS/DOM and maybe some small `<canvas>` elements sprinkled around as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any benefit in using canvas for some buttons and a moving seek bar. [Groovshark](http://grooveshark.com/) and [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/) using `div`s ant it's totally fine and working great. I can understand that you want to do something experimental but IE8 will be around for next 5 years. So thinking of a canvas only solution is recommended for commercial product.